# How do I get code-churn statistics by user?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

Microsoft Line of Code Counter is a tool for statistics code line in TFS, can count code changes between different version, different date, BUT can't count code for different users?

Is there possible to count code by user(who checked in code) and version?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  You can get this through the TFS Warehouse Analysis Services cube, or from the TFS Warehouse database.

Specifically take a look at the `dbo.Code Churn` table in `TFSWarehouse`.  You will need SQL skills to be able to pull this information together.

This is how you get the metric.  However, I recommend against using it.  A *good* programmer will check in about 15 lines of code per day on average (*yes, that's hyperbole*).  Using a code churn metric will not tell you who is working best, it will only tell you who is putting the most stuff into source control.

Comment: I'm fascinated by the the 15 lines of code figure. Can you explain how you came up with this number?

Comment: Mostly hyperbole, but consider that a *good* programmer's job is more than just typing into the IDE, it includes analysis, design, refactoring, etc.  The main point here is that code churn should not be used to tell you who your best developer is.  Thinking back two years ago to when I wrote this, I know that I saw that number somewhere, but, for now, consider it to be an illustration to the point.

Comment: Any useful refactoring (more than just renaming something) is going to change way more than 15 lines of code ;)